# add error for sfValidatorOr in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorOr(
  array(
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('email', '!=', ''),
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('phone', '!=', ''),
  ),
  array(),
  array('invalid' => 'Campo obligatorio')
));
```

Error is in $form->getGlobalErrors(). How can i add

**array('throw_global_error' => true),**

same as here:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorOr(
    array(
      new sfValidatorAnd( 
        array(
          new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('date_from', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'date_to',
            array('throw_global_error' => true),
            array('invalid' => 'The start date ("%left_field%") must be equal the end date ("%right_field%")')),
          new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('time_from', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::LESS_THAN, 'time_to',
            array('throw_global_error' => true),
            array('invalid' => 'The start time ("%left_field%") must be before the end time ("%right_field%")')),
       )),
          new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('date_from', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::LESS_THAN, 'date_to',
            array('throw_global_error' => true),
            array('invalid' => 'The start date ("%left_field%") must be before the end date ("%right_field%")')),
    )
  ));
```

?

i will render this :

```
<?php $form['email']->renderLabel() ?>
**<?php echo $form['email']->getError() ?>**
```

but in sfValidatorOr this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can put the throw_global_error option directly on sfValidatorSchemaCompare().

There is **no way** to put it on the sfValidatorOr as it's not a sfValidatorSchema object.